# Insert functions-defined constant into get_tags code

Tags: constants

I'm using the below code from WordPress' [get_tags Function Reference page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags)

```
    $tags = get_tags();
    $html = '<div class="post_tags">';
    foreach ($tags as $tag){
          $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);      
          $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
          $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";}
    $html .= '</div>';
    echo $html;
```

In my functions.php file I have a number of defined constants.

```
 define('xyz_city','New York');
```

I need to insert a constant into the tag link title (line 5 of above code). So instead of .....

```
    title='{$tag->name} Tag'
```

it needs to be .....

```
    title='{$tag->name} [insert xyz_city]'
```

But it's proving beyond my ability. Normally I echo the constants in like this

```
    <?php echo xyz_city ;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are going for:

```
$html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} {$xyz_city}' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
```

The `{$tag->name}` part is a way to insert a function or variable into a "double quoted" string definition. In the case of `{$tag->name}` it needs the {curly braces} to get the whole object->method thing to work. You can usually leave the curly braces out when you have a double quoted string and want to insert a variable like `$xyx_city`, but its good practice to put them in there anyway just in case the underscore or something else in the name messes up the string parsing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation miahelf. In hindsight, I think I failed to properly explain that the code is in two different files. The get_tags code is in my index.php file, whereas xyz_city is defined in  functions.php (like so: define('xyz_city','New York');). So can I reference {$xyz_city} in index.php when it's only defined in functions.php?

Comment: Hmmm I think I need to see more of the functions.php and index.php code to help you out on that one.

Comment: The functions.php code is "define('xyz_city','New York');". And that constant gets echoed in to any file with "<?php echo xyz_city ;?>"